# Unable to authenticate with OneLogin via Keycloak OpenID-Connect

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak, onelogin, scim

Afternoon all...

I'm trying to connect [Keycloak](http://keycloak.org) IdM with [OneLogin](https://www.onelogin.com) using the OpenID-Connect protocol.

I've managed to get both sides setup, however when I attempt to authenticate via Keycloak, I get the following error:

```
Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No access_token from server.
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.verifyAccessToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:297)
```

Running Keycloak with DEBUG logging, I'm able to see an error code being returned from OneLogin as follows:

```
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "POST /oidc/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Length: 677[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "Host: ***.onelogin.com[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_112)[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
2017-09-26 16:38:09,986 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 >> "code=**redacted**&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=**redacted**&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fidm01.**redacted-url**%2Fendpoint&client_id=**redacted**"    
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 15:38:10 GMT[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "X-Powered-By: Express[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "Content-Length: 108[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "[\r][\n]"  
2017-09-26 16:38:10,391 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-4) http-outgoing-2 << "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"client_secret must be provided in the Authorization header"}"
```

Sounds fairly simple, however when looking around, I'm seeing conflicting information on whether the 'Authorization' header is essential if the request contains the *client_id* and *client_secret*.
E.g. [Google Identity Platform docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode) and [Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant)

So is this a bug in Keycloak, or a bug in OneLogin?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Regards
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Keycloak, but we expect the clientid/secret to be sent as Basic auth headers, not in the URL or the Body of the request (which is what it looks like it's doing)

Comment: Cheers for the response.  

What I'm struggling to find is where that requirement is mandated on the OIDC spec, and therefore whether it is a bug in Keycloak or an implementation quirk in how OneLogin have implemented the spec?